# jQuery - Form input return confirm to delete

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I struggled a lot before posting here :) now, I want to replace my default javascript confirmation for deleting a file. I saw a lot of examples here, but no example with form input.

Now I have his form:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<{$pid}>" />
<input type="hidden" name="picture" value="<{$lang_del_pic}>" />
<input type="image" src="<{xoImgUrl}>img/del-icon.gif" width="16" height="16" align="bottom" border="0" alt="Delete media" name="pictured" value="<{$lang_del_pic}>" onclick="javascript: return confirm('<{$lang_confirm_del}>');" />
</form>
```

Now, I did everything, I have this div:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
 <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
  $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");


  $("#dialog-confirm").html('This dialog will show every time!');  
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   title: 'Kur za berbatov',
   resizable: false,
   height:140,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
    'Delete all items': function() {
     document.location = 'delete.php';

    },
    Cancel: function() {
     $(this).dialog('close');
    }
   }
  });


  $('form#dialog-confirm').submit(function(){
            $("input#pictured").html($("input#pictured").val());
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }); 


  $('input#opener').click(function() {
   $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
  }); 

 });
 </script>
```

and this new form:

```
<form name="dialog-confirm"  id="dialog-confirm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<{$pid}>" />
<input type="hidden" name="picture" value="<{$lang_del_pic}>" />
<input type="image" src="<{xoImgUrl}>img/del-icon.gif" width="16" height="16" align="bottom" border="0" alt="Delete media" name="pictured" value="" id="opener"  />
</form>
```

On press, I call successfuly the jQuery modal diolog, and everything works, but somehow, when I press 'delete all' the script tells me - "the script is called without the necessary parameters"

Now I guess I am failig to send the pic ID to be deleted with the jQuery, .. but do not know how to fix it. Any ideas ?

**Update**

Well, I have posted the original form, the new form, and the jQuery... I really can not do it... please take a look at the post up.

Is there no way doing it as I posted it, without an submit button. I mean the original works fine, however, I have hard times implementing it in the jQuery

P.S. I messedup with my accounts here, this is a new one :)

**Update 2**

Now this should work according all tutorials. But the delete button still does not submit the form... Why is that, please help me..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
            $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");


            $("#dialog-confirm").html('This dialog will show every time!');     
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Kur za berbatov',
                resizable: false,
                height:140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Delete all items': function() {
                        document.dialog-confirm.submit(); 

                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });


            $('form#dialog-confirm').submit(function(){
                $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
                return false;
            }); 

        });
        </script>



<form action="delete.php" name="dialog-confirm"  id="dialog-confirm"  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<{$pid}>" />
<input type="hidden" name="picture" value="<{$lang_del_pic}>" />
<input type="image" src="http://7est2.mqsto.com/themes/exnews/img/del-icon.gif" width="16" height="16" align="bottom" border="0" alt="Delete media" name="pictured" value="" id="opener"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site works a little differently than traditional forums. The Question-Asker should rarely ever post multiple items. If you wish to give progress updates, you should edit your question and append the new information.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you submit the form with a submit button and if the form is submitted you can get the id by:

```
var id = 0;
$("form").submit(function(){
     id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

now you get a global var and you can use it in your other functions

```
   buttons: {
    'Delete all items': function() {
    ...
    build an Ajax call here you can use id 
    ...     
    },
```

**Update**

instead of useing `document.dialog-confirm.submit();`

I should use:

```
$('#dialog-confirm').submit();
```

**Update 2**

take a look at `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` maybe you place the code wrong or something. and try to work with `alert()` to debug your javascript

Comment: could you propose a full example ? How do I change the form

Comment: mmm I maybe don't understand your question. where do you need what id? or do you want to change your form?

Comment: @Michel Stack Overflow is not a traditional forum. Here, users are expected to post only one answer and to update it as more information becomes available. I've coalesced your posts into one.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson, I lost my account with which I have posted this, and I can not update the original post. Please merge my posts whit the account I am writing with now i one post.

Comment: @michel, I have cheched everything, it is all ok. Nothing I am missing. Please suggest me the entire code. I will try whatever you sugest

Comment: Did test what you suggested. Replaced this:

$('dialog-confirm').submit();

with this:


$(document).ready(function() {
 alert('hi');
console.log($("#combobox"));
});

and I get the alert... huh... suggestions ?